# How to generate RANDOM traffic via Pktgen-DPDK?

Tags: dpdk

I use `range <portlist> src|dst ip <SMMI> <ipaddr>` as the [pktgen doc](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#runtime-options-and-commands), and `start all` to send out packets. But it doesn't work. Do I miss some steps?

Comment: please share the version for pktgen, DPDK and OS. If you are using physical interface the driver and firmware version. Also share `pktgen cmdline used` for easier debug. Hence marking the question `needs clarification`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DPDK PKTGEN does not dynamically create randaom packets, instead it can be programmed with `range` option for desired `start, minimum, maximum and increment factor`. To generate packets with DST-MAC address for a given range using the following commands in pktgen cli

```
enable all range
page range
range all dst mac start 00:00:00:00:00:01
range all dst mac min   00:00:00:00:00:01
range all dst mac max   ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
range all dst mac inc   00:00:00:00:00:01
```

As per [pkgetn range options](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#runtime-options-and-commands) one can change MAC, IP, VLAN, MPLS and GRE with `range` option.

[image]

note: tested on `pktgen-20.03.0`

Comment: if you find the answer useful and solves the problem accept and upvote.

Comment: Thank you so much! I missed the `enable all range` command